# How/when to seed the PRNG for OpenSSL / M2Crypto?

Tags: python, random, openssl, cryptography, m2crypto

I am using the [M2Crypto](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto) library to generate PKCS#7 signatures in a Python webapp.  M2Crypto's example code includes a line to seed OpenSSL's PRNG from a file:

```
from M2Crypto import BIO, Rand, SMIME

def makebuf(text):
    return BIO.MemoryBuffer(text)

# Make a MemoryBuffer of the message.
buf = makebuf('a sign of our times')

# Seed the PRNG.
Rand.load_file('randpool.dat', -1)

# Instantiate an SMIME object; set it up; sign the buffer.
s = SMIME.SMIME()
s.load_key('signer_key.pem', 'signer.pem')
p7 = s.sign(buf, SMIME.PKCS7_DETACHED)
```

My application is initializing an SMIME context and using it to sign multiple messages.  From the above code, it is not clear how I should be seeding the PRNG.

- Should I seed once at application startup, or before each signature?
- What should I use as an entropy source?
- Do I need to do something about entropy depletion if the application runs for a long time?

---

OpenSSL's [documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:RAND_add(3)) indicates that:

> On systems that provide /dev/urandom, the randomness device is used to seed the PRNG transparently.

My code will be running in Ubuntu, so the above suggests that the PRNG will be seeded automatically.  But [another documentation page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers#Seeds) states:

> The `urandom` device may lack sufficient entropy for your needs, and you might want to reseed it immediately from `/dev/random`.

I'm not sure how to evaluate whether or not `/dev/urandom` provides "sufficient entropy for [my] needs".

There is a function `RAND_status()` that is supposed to indicate whether "the PRNG has been seeded with enough data", but it's not clear what this means for practical purposes.

Comment: [Myths about /dev/urandom](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) and [When to use /dev/random vs /dev/urandom](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/324209/27142)

Comment: Also see [Random Numbers](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers) on the OpenSSL wiki. The wiki advises to seed the PRNG at startup, and any time you feel like you need it. And you should always reseed after a `fork`. When in doubt, throw 32-bytes at it. On mobile apps, like [Android and iOS](https://github.com/noloader), I even sample the on-device sensors and mix those in.